# Is it legal in England for unpasteurised dairy products to be sold in retail stores?

Tags: england-and-wales, food, food-processing, retail

[image: Isigny Ste Mère Crème d’Isigny]

I understand that it is not legal to sell unpasteurised dairy products in retail stores in England, at least in the case of raw milk. (It must be purchased directly from farmers.)

But then one sees other dairy products like raw butter or crème fraîche.

In particular, I understand that the  Isigny Ste Mère dairy production cooperative produces raw dairy products and see their butter and crème fraîche sold in chain grocery stores. What is the legality of that?

Comment: What makes you think that the pictured product is unpasteurized?

Comment: Something I read or heard a while back that suggested the whole brand’s product line is.  What makes you think it isn’t?

Comment: I think it isn't because at https://www.isigny-ste-mere.com/en/our-creams/our-cream-making-know-how/ they say "Our Isigny PDO crème fraîche is made the traditional way. Milk is skimmed so as to obtain the required fat content, before being gently pasteurised. ..."

Comment: I did see some references to raw dairy products sold under this brand, but this product certainly seems not to be one of them.  I have no idea whether any of their raw products is sold in the UK.

Comment: @phoog okay, good find. Have you seen anything suggesting the butter to be raw or not? Because that is also sold in supermarkets.

Comment: Search for the word "raw" on the page https://www.isigny-ste-mere.com/en/our-butters/our-buttermaking-know-how/ and for "label" in the regulations linked in Dale M's answer.  Also see schedule 5 of those regulations, "REQUIREMENTS FOR MILK USED FOR THE MANUFACTURE OF MILK-BASED PRODUCTS"

Answer (score 4):

### It’s legal

The [regulations](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1995/1086/made) provide limits on various bacteria. If the product is made from raw milk, the manufacturer must implement a testing regime for those bacteria. If it’s made from treated milk, they avoid this cost.

Comment: May I ask how did you go about finding and identifying these as the relevant regulations?

Comment: @Seekinganswers google - how does anyone find anything?